# Amazon Product Advertising API - Response Groups - no content for "EditorialReview" & "Reviews"?

Tags: php, api, amazon-product-advertising-api

does somebody get any content for "EditorialReview" or "Reviews" out of the "ResponseGroup"?

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/2010-11-01/DG/RG_EditorialReview.html
http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/2010-11-01/DG/RG_Reviews.html

I get no reviews or something similar in the response... i know Amazon is not providing reviews anymore but IFrames ... but those infos are also not in the xml feed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am able to get an editorialreviews node back. Here is what I invoke the Amazon service with the following arguments: Operation=ItemLookup, ASIN=B004V8W54Q, Version=2010-11-01, ResponseGroup=EditorialReview

```
<item>
  <asin>B004V8W54Q
  </asin>
  <editorialreviews>
    <editorialreview>
      <source>Product Description
      </source>
      <content>Jonathan Pryce (Pirates of the Caribbean) Robert De Niro (The Godfather) and Michael Palin (Monty Python and the Holy Grail) star in this landmark cult classic that dazzles ...
      </content>
      ...
    </editorialreview>
  </editorialreviews>
</item>
```

Make sure that you have similar arguments than the ones above. If you do and it still does not work, please post your request and I'll take a look at it.

Comment: Hi @user635090, yes when using "ItemLookup" it works but i wanna show a snippet of the editorialreview beside the search results ("ItemSearch"). Do you get the node with "ItemSearch" too? If not i must do for every result of the ItemSearch an ItemLookup-request...

Comment: No review on ItemLookup too! :-( `http://ecs.amazonaws.de/onca/xml?AWSAccessKeyId=...&IdType=ASIN&ItemId=3810523690&Operation=ItemLookup&ResponseGroup=Large%2CReviews%2CEditorialReview&Service=AWSECommerceService&Timestamp=2011-07-05T22%3A45%3A08Z&Version=2009-03-31&Signature=...`

Comment: Roman, I am able to get the editorialReview using ItemSearch as well... Can you try using a different API version (2010-11-01 instead of 2009-03-31)?